# How to prove Eq. (2.4.5) in Polchinski's string theory book?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, string-theory, conformal-field-theory

I got one more stupid question in Polchinski's string theory book. In p. 44, it is said

> *The currents* 
>     $$j(z)=i v(z) T(z), \tilde{j}(\bar{z}) = i v(z)^* \tilde{T}(\bar{z}) \tag{2.4.5}$$ 
>   *are conserved for any holomorphic $v(z)$.*

Did he mean 
$$\partial_z j(z)=0, \qquad \partial_{\bar{z}} \tilde{j}({\bar{z}})=0? $$ 
How to show that? The previous page states $\bar{\partial} T_{zz} = \partial T_{\bar{z} \bar{z}} =0 $. It seems these relations are insufficient to derive Eq. (2.4.5).

Comment: He means $\partial_{\bar z} j(z) = 0$ and $\partial_z {\tilde j}({\bar z}) = 0$.

Comment: I see.............................make sense........Thank you very much!